# How to collect individual results of the threads within a block?

Tags: cuda

In my Kernel, the threads are processing a small part of an array in global memory. 
After processing I would also like to set a flag indicating that the result of the calculation is zero for all threads within a block:

```
__global__ void kernel( int *a, bool *blockIsNull) { 
  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int result = 0;
  // {...} Here calculate result
  a[tid] = result;

  // some code here, but I don't know, that's my question...
  if (condition)
    blockIsNull[blockIdx.x] = true; // if all threads have returned result==0
}
```

Each individual thread owns the information. But I don't find an efficient way to collect it.

For example, I could have a counter in shared memory that is atomically incremented by each thread when `result==0`. So when the counter reaches `blockDim.x` it means that all threads have returned zero. Althought not tested, I am afraid that this solution will have a negative impact on performance (atomic functions are slow).

A zero result does not occur very often, so it is very unlikely to have zeros for all threads within a block. I would like to find a solution that has little impact on the performance in the general case.

What would be your recommendation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to perform a block level reduction of the condition value across a block. Just about all CUDA hardware supports a set of very useful warp voting primitives. You could use the `__all()` warp vote to determine that each warp of threads satisfied the condition, and then use `__all()` again to check whether all warps satisfy the condition. In code, it might look like this:

```
__global__ void kernel( int *a, bool *blockIsNull) { 

    // assume that threads per block is <= 1024
    __shared__ volatile int blockcondition[32];
    int laneid = threadIdx.x % 32;
    int warpid = threadIdx.x / 32;

    // Set each condition value to non zero to begin
    if (warpid == 0) {
        blockcondition[threadIdx.x] = 1;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    //
    // your code goes here
    //

    // warpcondition holds the vote from each warp
    int warpcondition = __all(condition);

    // First thread in each warp loads the warp vote to shared memory
    if (laneid == 0) {
        blockcondition[warpid] = warpcondition;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    // First warp reduces all the votes in shared memory
    if (warpid == 0) {
        int result = __all(blockcondition[threadIdx.x] != 0);

        // first thread stores the block result to global memory
        if (laneid == 0) {
             blockIsNull[blockIdx.x] = (result !=0);     
        }
    }
}
```

[ Huge disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled or tested, use at own risk ]

This code should (I think) work for any number of threads per block up to 1024. You could, if required, adjust the size of `blockcondition` to a smaller value if you were confident of an upper block size limit less than 1024. Probably the smartest way would be to use C++ templating and make the warp count limit a template parameter.

Comment: I didn't know the warp level `__all()` vote function but it seems to be the appropriate answer. I will test it in the future. Thanks !